# How to use composite key in WHERE IN clause

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-criteria

Table structure :

```
CREATE TABLE `Student` (
  `RollNumber` bigint(20) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Standard` bigint(20) NOT NULL,
  `Div_db` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Stud_code` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `Name_DB` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `DateOfBirth` datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`RollNumber`),
  UNIQUE KEY `UK_Student` (`Stud_code`,`Div_db`)
)
```

I have to make query from this table using composite key in WHERE IN clause for performance reason.
e.g.

```
SELECT * FROM Student WHERE ( Stud_code, Div ) IN (( 'C1', 'D1' ), ( 'C2', 'D2' ).....( 'Cn', 'Dn' ));
```

How to do this by using hibernate criteria?

**EDIT:**

I am using Dynamic Model

**Entity HBM :**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-mapping PUBLIC 
 "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Mapping DTD//EN"
 "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-mapping-3.0.dtd"> 

<hibernate-mapping>
    <class entity-name="Student" table="Student" dynamic-insert="true" mutable="true" polymorphism="implicit" dynamic-update="true" select-before-update="false" optimistic-lock="version" batch-size="1">
        <meta attribute="class-description">
            This class mapping info of Student
        </meta>
        <id name="RollNumber" type="int" column="RollNumber">
           <generator class="native"/>
        </id>
        <version name="Standard" access="field" column="Standard" type="int" unsaved-value="undefined" generated="never"/>
        <property name="Name" type="java.lang.String" column="Name_DB" unique="false" optimistic-lock="true" lazy="false" generated="never"/>
        <property name="DateOfBirth" type="java.util.Date" column="DateOfBirth" unique="false" optimistic-lock="true" lazy="false" generated="never"/>
        <properties name="UK_Student" unique="true" insert="true" update="true" optimistic-lock="true">
            <property name="Stud_code" type="java.lang.String" column="Stud_code" unique="false" optimistic-lock="true" lazy="false" generated="never"/>
            <property name="Div" type="java.lang.String" column="Div_db" unique="false" optimistic-lock="true" lazy="false" generated="never"/>
        </properties>
    </class>
```

Reading records using Hibernate criteria from entity:

```
Criteria fetchCriteria = session.createCriteria("Student");
fetchCriteria.setMaxResults(10000);

Disjunction disjunction = Restrictions.disjunction();

for (int i = 1; i <= 10000; i++) {
    Conjunction conjunction = Restrictions.conjunction();
    conjunction.add(Restrictions.eq("Stud_code", String.valueOf(i)));
    conjunction.add(Restrictions.eq("Div", "A"));
    disjunction.add(conjunction);
}

fetchCriteria.add(disjunction);

List resultList = fetchCriteria.setFirstResult(0).setResultTransformer(Criteria.ALIAS_TO_ENTITY_MAP).list();
```

**Query Which hibernate internally creates:**

```
Hibernate: select this_.RollNumber as RollNumb1_0_0_, this_.Standard as Standard2_0_0_, this_.Name_DB as Name_DB3_0_0_, this_.DateOfBirth as DateOfBi4_0_0_, this_.Stud_code as Stud_cod5_0_0_, this_.Div_db as Div_db6_0_0_ from Student this_ where ((this_.Stud_code=? and this_.Div_db=?) or (this_.Stud_code=? and this_.Div_db=?) or .....
```

But i want generate query which i mentioned earlier using Hibernate criteria due to some performance reason.

**Note**: I am using hibernate 4.3.8.

Comment: Server may decide to use your index... or not decide (and in most cases it is right). You may use index hints, of course, but in most cases you need do nothing.

Comment: @Akina I have to prepare composite key in WHERE IN clause query using Hibernate Criteria

Comment: If the key already exists than you need in nothing.

Comment: @Developer have you find a solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `Stud_code` and `Div` are part of an embeddable, you can use it like `select s from Student s where s.embeddable in :embeddables` and pass a collection of embeddables accordingly. Not sure what you are referring to specifically regarding "Hibernate Criteria" (JPA Criteria API or legacy Hibernate Criteria API), but there are plenty of tutorials online about how to use those APIs. If you still need help, you would also have to post the entity model that you are using.

Comment: I have added by hbm and other details. Thanks